# Good way of handling NoneType objects when printing in Python

Tags: python, string

How do I go about printin a NoneType object in Python?

```
# score can be a NonType object
logging.info("NEW_SCORE : "+score)
```

Also why is that sometime I see a comma instead of the + above?

Comment: There should be a hollow check mark below the down arrow - use that.  Also, you should use the up-arrow to vote for answers that are helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best approach is:

```
logging.info("NEW_SCORE: %s", score)
```

In most contexts, you'd have to use a `%` operator between the format string on the left and the value(s) on the right (in a tuple, if more than one). But the `logging` functions are special: you pass the format string as the first argument, then, one after the other, just as many arguments as needed to match the number of `%s` &c formatting markers in the format, and the `logging` functions will use the formatting operator `%s` as appropriate *if and only if* necessary -- so you don't incur any runtime overhead if your current logging level is such that, e.g., `logging.info` is not actually going to be shown.

Forget `str` calls and `+`-based string concatenation anyway -- even without `logging`'s specials, `%`-formatting is really the way to go (in Python 2.6 or earlier; in 2.6 or later, you should also consider strings' `format` method, allowing clearer and more readable expression of what amounts to the same functionality).

Answer (score 7):

```
logging.info("NEW_SCORE : " + str(score))
```

Proof by Python interpreter:

```
>>> x = None
>>> "x: " + x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
>>> "x: " + str(x)
'x: None'
```

QED

Comment: Is there a way to check if it is NoneType?

Comment: You can do something like `logging.info("NEW_SCORE : " + score or "No score")`.  If `score` is None or an empty string then it will log "NEW_SCORE : No score".

Answer (score 0):

For print purpose,you need to str first. A comma is to print with a single space between it..For example:

print "hi guys","how are you today"

*this syntax will output:*

hi guys how are you today

but it will be different if your syntax like this:

print "hi guys"+"how are you today"

*this syntax will output:*

hi guyshow are you today

Comment: This will work with the print statement (which implicitely calls `str`), but not in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

if not score==None: logging.info("NEW_SCORE : "+score)

or

logging.info("NEW_SCORE: %s" % str(score) )