# Python TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, string, format, typeerror

Here's the output.  These are utf-8 strings I believe... some of these can be NoneType but it fails immediately, before ones like that...

```
instr = "'%s', '%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'" % softname, procversion, int(percent), exe, description, company, procurl
```

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Its 7 for 7 though?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Note that the `%` syntax for formatting strings is becoming outdated. If your version of Python supports it, you should write:

```
instr = "'{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}'".format(softname, procversion, int(percent), exe, description, company, procurl)
```

This also fixes the error that you happened to have.

Comment: Does this work for the logging module as well?  Is this kind of interpolation understood by it?

Comment: @joshsvoss: yes, there are a few links mentioned here that discuss the possibilities: http://bugs.python.org/issue14031

Comment: @SimeonVisser, why is this becoming outdated? If you, for example, use one variable to store format string and you want to put string with replaced values in same variable you get just a tad bit cleaner code with **format_string %= ('bla', 'bla', 'bla')**. Care to elaborate or point to some useful link about this?

Comment: .format() was added because this is quite common and it shouldn't require an operator to do. Your example is nice but difficult to explain to a newcomer. The notation a = a.format(1,2,3) is much more explicit and easier to understand/teach. I don't have a link but this is the main reason why format() was introduced (ease of understanding).

Comment: Also, format() supports more explicit ways of expressing what happens, such as "{a} {b}".format(a='3', b='4').

Comment: I'm using python 3.6.5 and the percent sign operator still can be used...

Comment: @KhunRan: it hasn't been removed but there are now better ways to express what you wish to format, such as `.format()` and f-strings.

Comment: Nine years after this opinion was written, `%` still works (in Python 3.8.6).

Answer (score 288):

You need to put the format arguments into a tuple (add parentheses):

```
instr = "'%s', '%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'" % (softname, procversion, int(percent), exe, description, company, procurl)
```

What you currently have is equivalent to the following:

```
intstr = ("'%s', '%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'" % softname), procversion, int(percent), exe, description, company, procurl
```

Example:

```
>>> "%s %s" % 'hello', 'world'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
>>> "%s %s" % ('hello', 'world')
'hello world'
```

Comment: That worked..sort of.  I was trying to use %s formatting to avoid the NoneType error, but I'm getting it still.  Related:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338690/good-way-of-handling-nonetype-objects-when-printing-in-python

Comment: Won't be useful to the OP, given the age, but just in case still useful to someone: a simple workaround where a variable may be none is to guard against that with a ternary statement - i.e. "%s %s" % (a if a is not None else "", b) if we are worried about a possibly being None. So even if a is None we still aren't passing None to the format operator and causing problems.

Answer (score 27):

I got the same error when using `%` as a percent character in my format string.  The solution to this is to double up the `%%`.

Comment: Providing some code examples of how your solution works, and how it fails without it, etc. might be useful. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Note that this is a 5 year old question, so you should add an answer only if it provides significantly more information than those already there.

Comment: I got a variation of this error due to typo: `"foo: %(foo)s, bar: s(bar)% baz: %(baz)s" % {"foo": "FOO", "bar": "BAR", "baz": "BAZ"}`

Comment: For python3 this "solution" is wrong -> Invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I was using a *raw* query for a specific reason and this was to add double quotes in TIME_FORMAT function.

```
User.objects.raw(
            f'SELECT f1,f2,TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(end_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(start_time))),"%%H:%%i") AS log FROM users GROUP BY start_dt')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    sql = "insert into fd(province,pici,subject,maxscore,midscore,minscore,zy,school) values('%s', '%s','%s'," \
          "'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')"
    data = (item['province'],item['pici'],item['subject'],item['maxscore'],item['midscore'],item['minscore'],item['zy'],item['school'])

    self.cursor.execute(sql % data)
```