# Getting 'TypeError, not enough arguments for format string' while writing to file?

Tags: python, loops, text

I am trying to create a code that takes number from output and create a generate a text file
with that number , then write some lines in that file with that number in use ..

I tried to use the code :

```
   for i in Nums:
    sh1 = '%d.txt' %i
    target = open (sh1, 'w') ## a will append, w will over-write
    text = '%d * 0\n %d *1'
    target.write(text %(i))
    target.close()
```

but i face this error TypeError: not enough arguments for format string .
I do not understand this error why shows for me . I searched but solutions did not work with my code .

What i need from the code is to create the text file Like if i entered the number 1 . creates txt file name 1.txt and write these lines to it .

```
    1 * 0
    1 * 1
    1 * 2
    1 * 3
```

Any help ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: the [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146190/python-typeerror-not-enough-arguments-for-format-string) search result is actually helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the expression

```
text %(i)
```

`text` refers to the format string `'%d * 0\n %d *1'`, which contains two `%d` placeholders, but you’re only passing one argument, `i`. You need to do something like

```
text % (i, j)
```

For example, `text % (4, 5)` would give you

```
4 * 0\n 5 *1
```

By the way, it’s standard to include spaces both before and after the `%` operator used for formatting. And if you’re passing just one argument to a formatting operation and you want to use a tuple, you need to use syntax like `(i,)` instead of just `(i)`. You can read more about that rule [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750632/why-does-adding-a-trailing-comma-after-a-string-make-it-a-tuple).

Comment: What I mean is i need the the argument to pass for all the operation , I tried to use the comma but the same issue happens ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `str.format`?

```
for i in Nums:
    target = open('{}.txt'.format(i), 'w')
    target.write('{0} * 0\n{0} * 1\n{0} * 2\n{0} * 3\n'.format(i))
    target.close()
```

The use of `'%d.txt' %i` string format is slowly becoming less used, perhaps due it's slightly confusing usability. `str.format` is a bit more concise and provides you bit the same functionality. You only need to specify the `{}` to signify where the parameter will go. You can further specify the index of the parameter inside the brackets, `{0}`, or `{1}`.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't know about this function