# For loop not working in python

Tags: python, for-loop

[in outer loop i=156 ,it is not looping for other values of i=1,2,3,4.......](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpG1h.png)I am trying to run this for loop in scrapy python . But first loop is not working

```
for i in range(1,157):
     start_urls = ["https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/producttype/apps?"
          "countryid=100&lang=en&page={}&pagesize={}&"
          "sortby=popular&licensetype=all&callback=_producttype_apps"
          "&_=1499255634459".format(i, page) for page in xrange(1,1001)]
```

The first loop outside the start_urls is not working
The results required is like this for page=1 pagesize should run from 1 to 1000 and when page=2 pagesize should again run from 1 to 1000 and so on till page=156

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python TypeError: not enough arguments for format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146190/python-typeerror-not-enough-arguments-for-format-string)

Comment: the `for` loop is fine, your problem is that you are misusing string formatting. have a look at https://pyformat.info/

Comment: You get a `TypeError` that states that your string formatting is wrong and you assume that the problem is the `for` loop?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to have multiple percent signs like that. As a simpler example, compare the results of `"%d%d" %23 %42` and `"%d%d" % (23,42)`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "is not working"? Does it throw an error? If that is the case, can you post the complete traceback? If it doesn't throw an error is the result you get and the result you expect different? If yes, what result would you expect and what result do you get?

Comment: @syntonym the value of i for first loop is starting from  156 not from 1

Comment: @emon - you are reassigning the whole list with each iteration, so only the final iteration exists by the time you exit the loop. I've put in an answer explaining and fixing this.

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly using `%` format strings, you could create a `tuple()` but it may be easier to use `.format()`. You can also split strings for better formatting:

```
start_urls = ["https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/producttype/apps?"
              "countryid=100&lang=en&page={}&pagesize={}&"
              "sortby=popular&licensetype=all&callback=_producttype_apps&"
              "_=1499255634459".format(i, page) for page in xrange(1,1001)]
```

Comment: I think you forget to add' page' after 'for'  "for page in xrange(1,1001)"

Comment: Thank you, fixed. And given the args, I imagine the OP has the variables the wrong way around too.

Comment: I am new  to python, first loop outside start_url is not running

Comment: It is running but I imagine you are not saving each time around the loop and are only seeing the last list of `start_urls`. Perhaps you meant `start_urls = []` outside of the loop and `start_urls.extend(['https://...])` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello Emon,**

Try this code,
In this below code use "\" so do not confuse because it is used for multiline code write and this functionality is python inbuilt provides.

```
for i in range(1,157):
    start_urls = ['https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/producttype/apps?' \
            'countryid=100&lang=en&' \
            'page=%d' \
            '&pagesize=%s'\
            '&sortby=popular&licensetype=all&callback=_producttype_apps&_=1499255634459' % (i,page) for page in xrange(1,1001)]

    # Display starts_urls 
    print(start_urls)
```

**Using the Format Method,**
Accessing Arguments by Position

```
for i in range(1,157):
    start_urls = ['https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/producttype/apps?' \
            'countryid=100&lang=en&' \
            'page={0}' \
            '&pagesize={1}' \
            '&sortby=popular&licensetype=all&callback=_producttype_apps&_=1499255634459'.format(i,page) for page in xrange(1,1001)]
```

When you use long any type string/content so I suggest that use the `format method` because of any time easily you understand the code.

**More example for this below link read,**
1. https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop
2. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/820236/Python-String-Formatting-Using-format-Method

**I hope my answer is helpful. Any query so comments, please.**

Comment: Sorry i know but, when i execute the code that time i will ckeck something and i forget the put orignal code.

Comment: And i am not expert so give anytime me suggest not down vote.

Comment: it now works, but the \ is still not necessary, but if you like it for style, i guess that's fine..

Comment: But not all the time we have to do scoral so best is this way.

Comment: You are right. But i am use python standards way to doing code.

Answer (score 0):

what your are probably trying to do is

```
start_urls = ["https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/producttype/apps?"
      "countryid=100&lang=en&page={}&pagesize={}&"
      "sortby=popular&licensetype=all&callback=_producttype_apps"
      "&_=1499255634459".format(i, page) for page in xrange(1,1001) for i in range(1,157)]
```

if the order matters, you can do it the other way around by reversing the for loops:

```
start_urls = ["https://appworld.blackberry.com/cas/producttype/apps?"
              "countryid=100&lang=en&page={}&pagesize={}&"
              "sortby=popular&licensetype=all&callback=_producttype_apps"
              "&_=1499255634459".format(i, page) for i in range(1,157) for page in xrange(1,1001)]
```

you're using two different loops in different ways - your use of the outer for loop is wrong. Think about this:

```
for i in range(10):
    x = i
```

for each iteration you assign the variable x with the value of i, but before you do anything else you reassign it to the next i. That is essentially what you're doing in your code.

alternatives include appending to a list:

```
x = []
for i in range(10):
    x.append(i)
```

or list comprehensions like you are using in your code

```
x = [i for i in range(10)]
```

obviously these are dumb examples because they are just reproducing the list from `range(10)`

Comment: In my case how shall i use it , sorry I am new to loops

Comment: @emon replace all the code you posted with the first code block from my answer (so you have 2 for loops inside the list comprehension). That should work, giving you a list of URLs for each page (1 to 1000) and each i (1 to 157)

Comment: @your code is not giving the desire results , the results required is like this for page=1 pagesize should run from 1 to 1000 and when page=2 pagesize should again run from 1 to 1000 and so on till page=156

Comment: @emon if the order matters I have added how to change it.

Answer (score -1):

Try converting the list into a tuple first
Then look for formatter sensitively affects.

Comment: Hello Mustafajahjoum, this not the perfect answer so give the proper answer and also give the code so any person understand easily.