# Update table in MySQL using python dict

Tags: python, mysql

I have a dictionary of values where the keys are the column names. I want to send a single update statement that included all of the data to update. I loop through the dict keys and then add the corresponding values during the query.  I am stuck on how to move forward. Here is what I have:

```
cart={}
sn = request.form['cartSN']
cart["camera_front_SN"] = request.form['frontCameraSN']
cart["battery_board_SN"] = request.form['batterySN']
cart["speaker_board_SN"] = request.form['speakerSN']
cart["ibcs_SN"] = request.form['ibcsSN']
table = 'cart_info'
sql = 'UPDATE '+table+' SET {} WHERE cart_SN = '+sn+' '.format(', '.join('{}=%s'.format(k) for k in cart))
print(sql)
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="nope",
                     password="*******",
                     db="cart_data")
cur = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cur.execute(sql, [cart.values()])
db.commit()
db.close()
```

When I run this i get the following error:

```
    [2018-03-25 06:08:39,972] ERROR in app: Exception on /update [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Colin Roberts\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 238, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Colin Roberts\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Colin Roberts\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Colin Roberts\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Colin Roberts\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Colin Roberts\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Colin Roberts\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "FlaskApp.py", line 154, in cartUpdate
    cur.execute(sql, [cart.values()])
  File "C:\Users\Colin Roberts\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 240, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, str(m))
  File "C:\Users\Colin Roberts\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 52, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass(errorvalue)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I am stuck. Also, I don't like this 'your post is mostly code; please add more details". No, my post is mostly error message. However, I would rather include too much error message than not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your SQL

```
sql = 'UPDATE '+table+' SET {} WHERE cart_SN = '.format(', '.join('{}=%s'.format(k) for k in cart))+sn
```

Because in your case

```
sql = 'UPDATE '+table+' SET {} WHERE cart_SN = '+sn+' '.format(', '.join('{}=%s'.format(k) for k in cart))
```

format is applied to `' '.fomat()`  empty string not the main string

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and got a different error, which is progress!! I am now getting 

    TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: may this link help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146190/python-typeerror-not-enough-arguments-for-format-string

Comment: That did it. I needed single quotes around the sn variable. Thank you all!!

Comment: Welcome!! @ColinRoberts