# MySQL TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench

When I retrieve data from Mysql using datetime the below error occurred
**TypeError: not enough arguments for format string**. This is my code written in below

```
temp1=datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d')
temp2=datetime.strptime(date2, '%Y-%m-%d')
rows1=exdb.getData("admin", "SELECT count(id) as total_count from client_onboard WHERE (video_datetime BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s');" % (temp1) %(temp2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a **tuple** for your string formatting:

```
from datetime import datetime

date1 = "2018-01-01"
date2 = "2018-02-01"

# Date parsing
temp1 = datetime.strptime(date1, '%Y-%m-%d')
temp2 = datetime.strptime(date2, '%Y-%m-%d')

rows1 = exdb.getData("admin",
    """SELECT count(id) as total_count from client_onboard
    WHERE (video_datetime BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s');""" % (temp1, temp2)
)
```

#### Warning: SQL Injection

You should **not** use string formatting for SQL queries where the input is untrusted -- e.g. comes from the user. This makes your code vulnurable for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The `cursor` object of the Python DBAPI can handles this for you, e.g.:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM platforms WHERE language = %s;", (platform,))
```

Comment: Can you please mark this answer as solution then? :)

Answer (score 1):

[The answer in this question thread should solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146190/python-typeerror-not-enough-arguments-for-format-string).

You should use `.format()` instead.