# Python update data with pymsql

Tags: python, sql, sql-update, pymysql

Hi when I update data with sql, I get a string error. Please help me.

This is  my error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format stringimport pymysql.connect string error
```

My code is as follows:

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='1234', host='localhost', database='sosyalbe')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM siparisler WHERE siparis_durum ='İptal'")

order = cursor.fetchone()
id = order[0]

dss = 10
cursor.execute("UPDATE siparisler SET urun_baslangic = '%s' WHERE order_id ='%s'" %dss % id)  #errror

cursor.execute("UPDATE siparisler SET urun_baslangic = (?) WHERE id = (?)" (dss, id))   #ERROR
```

please help !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python TypeError: not enough arguments for format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146190/python-typeerror-not-enough-arguments-for-format-string)

Comment: i read this topic but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma between the string and tuple of arguments. Also, note that the `%s`s should **not** be surrounded with quotes, as they are not string literals:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE siparisler SET urun_baslangic = %s WHERE order_id = %s", (dss, id))
```

Comment: @omer see my latest edit. If it still doesn't work, please share the error message.

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting